# oleDbDataAdapter Update string

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

My goal is to take table from database, modify and put it back to the same place.

I decided to use oleDbDataAdapter.Fill/.Update routine to prevent cell-by-cell updating and speed up the process. Reading Table from mdb.DataBase into DataTable was succesful, and modyfying went ok, but I've failed with update a database.

I can suppose two ways from where I'm getting troubles:
1. adapter.UpdateCommand is wrong
2. (some) critical parameter(s) missed before calling of adapter.update(datatable)

While fixing point 1

- I've included primary key into select query
- I tried to use dbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
- I was trying to copy update string from dbCommandBuilder properties and use it like a sting parameter 
  Fail.

While fixing point 2

I've realised option of using UpdateCommand.Parameters and direct filling of target database in the loop, row by row and element by element. But I'm trying to avoid it and update whole table at once.

Could you explain what do I miss?

here's a code example

```
                    Dim connetionString As String
                    Dim oledbCnn As OleDbConnection
                    Dim oledbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
                    Dim sssql, susql As String

connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sMDBFile & ";"
sssql = "SELECT MAPINFO_ID, " & SFieldName & ", AB_P_PIND, AB_P_CITY, " _
  & "AB_P_DISTR, AB_P_SDISTR, AB_P_STR, AB_P_NUM, AB_P_BLD, AB_P_LIT, AB_P_XTRA, " _
  & "AB_P_XEPT, AB_UINF, AB_P_DONE FROM " & DBTableName
susql = "UPDATE " & DBTableName & " SET AB_P_PIND = @AB_P_PIND, AB_P_CITY = @AB_P_CITY, " _
  & "AB_P_DISTR = @AB_P_DISTR, AB_P_SDISTR = @AB_P_SDISTR, AB_P_STR = @AB_P_STR, " _
  & "AB_P_NUM = @AB_P_NUM, AB_P_BLD = @AB_P_BLD, AB_P_LIT = @AB_P_LIT, AB_P_XTRA = @AB_P_XTRA, " _
  & "AB_P_XEPT = @AB_P_XEPT, AB_UINF = @AB_UINF, AB_P_DONE = @AB_P_DONE WHERE MAPINFO_ID = @MAPINFO_ID"
'susql = "UPDATE TabVer1 SET Адрес = ?, AB_P_PIND = ?, AB_P_CITY = ?, AB_P_DISTR = ?, AB_P_SDISTR = ?, " _
'  & "AB_P_STR = ?, AB_P_NUM = ?, AB_P_BLD = ?, AB_P_LIT = ?, AB_P_XTRA = ?, AB_P_XEPT = ?, " _
'  & "AB_UINF = ?, AB_P_DONE = ? WHERE ((MAPINFO_ID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Адрес IS NULL) OR " _
'  & "(Адрес = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_PIND IS NULL) OR (AB_P_PIND = ?)) AND " _
'  & "((? = 1 AND AB_P_CITY IS NULL) OR (AB_P_CITY = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_DISTR IS NULL) " _
'  & "OR (AB_P_DISTR = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_SDISTR IS NULL) OR (AB_P_SDISTR = ?)) AND " _
'  & "((? = 1 AND AB_P_STR IS NULL) OR (AB_P_STR = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_NUM IS NULL) " _
'  & "OR (AB_P_NUM = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_BLD IS NULL) OR (AB_P_BLD = ?)) AND " _
'  & "((? = 1 AND AB_P_LIT IS NULL) OR (AB_P_LIT = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_XTRA IS NULL) OR " _
'  & "(AB_P_XTRA = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_XEPT IS NULL) OR (AB_P_XEPT = ?)) AND " _
'  & "((? = 1 AND AB_UINF IS NULL) OR (AB_UINF = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND AB_P_DONE IS NULL) OR (AB_P_DONE = ?)))"
' second ver of sussql (under comments) is taken from dbCommandBuilder's properties                    


oledbCnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
Try
   oledbCnn.Open()
   oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
   dTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dTable.Columns("MAPINFO_ID")}
      'Dim DbCommandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter)
      ' here's some illustrations of different ways I've tried with update strings
   oledbAdapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sssql, oledbCnn)
      'oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = DbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
   oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand(susql, oledbCnn)

   oledbAdapter.Fill(dTable)

   ''' dTable modification

   dTable.AcceptChanges()
      ' DataTable updates 
   oledbAdapter.Update(dTable)
      ' Database does not
   oledbAdapter.Dispose()
   oledbCnn.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your code: use parameters to avoid sql injection, use the `Using...End Using` format for your disposable objects, including the connection, adapter objects, etc.

For the immediate issue, try not calling the AcceptChanges until after you updated.  AcceptChanges is a flag that marks which rows are dirty.

```
oledbAdapter.Update(dTable)
dTable.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: thanks for Using ... End Using reminder. Concerning update table before aceeptChanges: it leads to exeption "one or more reqired parameters is mising".